# Automate copy paste Excel ranges dynamically from different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have tables in different sheets of excel and requirement is to copy second last row of table  to last row. Can someone pls help me how can we dynamically find table size so that code wont be required to change evrytime when table size changes? There are many tables and we want to automate this task using vba code and macro button.

I have written a code but that is range specific and everytime I need to update the range and process become cumbersome.

```
Sub history_copy()

Set obj = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet A")
obj.Range("E12:N12").Value = obj.Range("E11:N11").Value
obj.Range("E34:N34").Value = obj.Range("E33:N33").Value
obj.Range("E46:N46").Value = obj.Range("E45:N45").Value
obj.Range("E57:N57").Value = obj.Range("E56:N56").Value

Set obj1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet b ")
obj1.Range("G21:O21").Value = obj1.Range("G20:O20").Value

Set obj2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet c")
obj2.Range("D4:M4").Value = obj2.Range("D3:M3").Value
obj2.Range("D14:M14").Value = obj2.Range("D13:M13").Value
obj2.Range("D23:M23").Value = obj2.Range("D22:M22").Value
obj2.Range("D33:M33").Value = obj2.Range("D32:M32").Value
obj2.Range("D43:M43").Value = obj2.Range("D42:M42").Value
obj2.Range("D52:M52").Value = obj2.Range("D51:M51").Value
obj2.Range("D61:M61").Value = obj2.Range("D60:M60").Value
obj2.Range("D70:M70").Value = obj2.Range("D69:M69").Value
obj2.Range("D79:M79").Value = obj2.Range("D78:M78").Value
obj2.Range("D88:M88").Value = obj2.Range("D87:M87").Value
obj2.Range("D97:M97").Value = obj2.Range("D96:M96").Value
obj2.Range("D106:M106").Value = obj2.Range("D105:M105").Value
obj2.Range("D114:M114").Value = obj2.Range("D113:M113").Value

Set obj3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet d")
obj3.Range("D4:L4").Value = obj3.Range("D3:L3").Value



Set obj5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet f")
obj5.Range("D4:L4").Value = obj5.Range("D3:L3").Value

Set obj6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet e")
obj6.Range("C4:C12").Value = obj6.Range("B4:B12").Value
obj6.Range("H4:H8").Value = obj6.Range("G4:G8").Value
obj6.Range("N4:N11").Value = obj6.Range("M4:M11").Value
obj6.Range("S4:S10").Value = obj6.Range("R4:R10").Value
obj6.Range("X4:X18").Value = obj6.Range("W4:W18").Value
obj6.Range("AD4:AD9").Value = obj6.Range("AC4:AC9").Value
obj6.Range("AI4:AI13").Value = obj6.Range("AH4:AH13").Value
obj6.Range("AO4:AO6").Value = obj6.Range("AN4:AN6").Value
obj6.Range("AT4:AT11").Value = obj6.Range("AS4:AS11").Value
obj6.Range("AY4:AY20").Value = obj6.Range("AX4:AX20").Value
obj6.Range("BD4:BD10").Value = obj6.Range("BC4:BC10").Value
obj6.Range("BI4:BI21").Value = obj6.Range("BH4:BH21").Value

Set obj7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet i")
obj7.Range("C4:C12").Value = obj7.Range("B4:B12").Value
obj7.Range("H4:H8").Value = obj7.Range("G4:G8").Value
obj7.Range("N4:N11").Value = obj7.Range("M4:M11").Value
obj7.Range("S4:S10").Value = obj7.Range("R4:R10").Value
obj7.Range("X4:X18").Value = obj7.Range("W4:W18").Value
obj7.Range("AD4:AD9").Value = obj7.Range("AC4:AC9").Value
obj7.Range("AI4:AI13").Value = obj7.Range("AH4:AH13").Value
obj7.Range("AO4:AO6").Value = obj7.Range("AN4:AN6").Value
obj7.Range("AT4:AT11").Value = obj7.Range("AS4:AS11").Value
obj7.Range("AY4:AY20").Value = obj7.Range("AX4:AX20").Value
obj7.Range("BD4:BD10").Value = obj7.Range("BC4:BC10").Value
obj7.Range("BI4:BI21").Value = obj7.Range("BH4:BH21").Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Please understand that this site is not a free programming service. We can help you if you get stuck with your code, but you have to be able to write code yourself. Post the code you have so far and explain what you need help with. Please edit your question to provide these details. Do not do that in a comment. Post a comment when you have updated your question to alert your followers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have now posted my code in question. Can you please now help me.

Comment: What is your data structure? You have several references to different rows in column E. What is the "second last row of the table"? How do you determine that you need rows 12, 34, 46 and 57 in that sheet? Do you have several tables in the sheet? Are these Excel Table Objects or are these just ranges with some empty rows followed by another range? Your code does not make sense unless we can see the data. Use an ad-free file sharing service to post a REDUCED data sample that illustrates the problem. Ad-free can be DropBox, Box, OneDrive.

Comment: we have tables in different sheets , we are copying todays value for that table to compare with tomorrows data. last row will have yesterday data and second last row will have todays. this table we have in different sheets and total we are taking in consideration like E2:H2. The range of table is not fixed for each table.

Comment: Can you please suggest how this can be done dynamically

Comment: Did you read my last comment about needing to know your data structure? If you don't provide a sample file with your data structure, nobody will be able to help you with your code. When will it be row 3? When will it be row 77? What are the markers to define the logic? If the range is `not fixed for each table`  -- pardon me, but how on earth is Excel going to know what to copy? YOU need to define the logic for that in words, relating to your sample data file that you post in an ad-free file sharing service. I think I'm done here.